# Performing a case in-sensitive search on a java List using stream().filter()

Tags: java, list, search, java-stream, case-insensitive

I'm trying to perform an case in-sensitive search on a Java List using `stream().filter(...)`.

My search function works fine but i haven't managed to implement this to work without case sensitivity. My function looks something like this:

```
public static List<License> searchByEverything(String keyword, String dealerid){
    List<License> licenseDealerList = getLicensesByDealer(dealerid);

   // org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(keyword);


    Predicate<License> licensePredicate = u -> u.name1.contains(keyword);
    List<License> filteredList = licenseDealerList.stream().filter(licensePredicate).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return filteredList;
}
```

As you can see i tried to use the apache commons library but i don't get it how to include it in my `stream().filter(...)`. I researched some different methods but didn't really understand how to implement any of them into my method. In my case it's really important that the search is performed from a string value on the object values and that it returns an object.

I know i could use something like `matchAny()` instead of `filter()` but i didn't understand how to return it as an object.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [toLowerCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()):

```
u -> u.name1.toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase());
```

This way both values are in the same case and your search is case in-sensitive.

Comment: Didn't expect it to be that simple. Thanks a lot, solved the problem for me.

Comment: Note that this method creates strings each time. Extra garbage collection. Depending if this is in a hot path and/or you have memory constraints or a need to reduce GCs, you may want to go with a functional ignoreCase option.

Answer (score 0):

Sensitive character filtering can use DFA algorithm, refer to: https://programmer.help/blogs/sensitive-word-filtering-aop-annotation-dfa-algorithm.html

Answer (score 0):

To make use of the Appache Commons' [StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(str, searchStr)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), do:

```
List<License> filteredList = licenseDealerList.stream()
                                .filter(u -> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(u.name1, keyword)) // Don't forget the import statement for StringUtils.
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```